# Android BroadcastReceiver: context issue

Tags: java, android, location, broadcastreceiver

I create an application that implements simple geolocation problem: once in, say, 20 minutes, it takes a LatLng coordinate.

For this purpose, from `MainActivity`, I initiate `BroadcastReceiver` to work. It instantiates `LocationManager` to find coordinates, which needs *application context*.

The **problem** is: due to memory reasons, Android OS can kill my `MainActivity`, so, `BroadcastReceiver`, firing next time, catches null pointer exception, referring to *application's context*.

**Ideas**:

I. I could restart the activity inside `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //start activity
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.MainActivity");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

but *context* is null due to killed Activity.

II. Maybe, the paradigm, presented in my solution, too cumbersome?
Maybe here is *graceful* solution, I even didn't think of?

Well, my **code** snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// ...

    public void onStartSessionButtonClicked (View view) {
        Intent alarmRecIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent mAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmRecIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(mAlarmIntent);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                RConstants.locUpdateInterval,
                mAlarmIntent
                );
    }
}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        Context mContext = context;
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                throw new Exception("network provider is not enabled");
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDTS,
                    MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDTS,
                    locationListener
            );
        }
        catch (Exception e) { /* catch codeblock */ }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your activity code.

Comment: Add your activity code also

Comment: @DharmendraPratapSingh,
Added

Comment: @W4R10CK, done.

Comment: Where are u using alarmreceiver ?

Comment: @W4R10CK, you see in `MainActivity` `setInexactRepeating`, that dedicates `AlarmReceiver` to fire (inexactly) every `RConstants.locUpdateInterval` milliseconds.

It is instantiated: 

`Intent alarmRecIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);`

Comment: did u tried creating `constructor` of `AlarmReceiver` and pass context ?

Comment: @W4R10CK, I suppose, *Context* is not an object, but a reference to it. Passing it through `AlarmReceiver` will cause the same issue. Yes, I'll try, but I don't hope it works.

Comment: @Constantine, let me know if works i will post answer :P

Comment: Hey, @W4R10CK, *context* is NOT really NULL! Check out my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

I really confused myself *supposing* that *context* comes NULL to `BroadcastReceiver's` *onReceive()* method, when MainActivity is killed by Android OS. The other one pointer came NULL in my code, so it caused exception.

If you interested, please, check out the code snippet below for details:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

LocationManager mlocationManager = null;
private CountDownTimer cdTimer = null;
private Context mContext;

final private static long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDTS = 1000 * 1; // ms
final private static float MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDTS = 5.0f; // meters

@Override
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context; // < -- 1 -- >
    try {
        mlocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!mlocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            throw new Exception("network provider is not enabled");
        }
        // < -- 2 -- >
        cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(RConstants.locUpdateTimeoutUsed, RConstants.locUpdateTimeoutUsed) {
            /// other required methods overridden here ...

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mlocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                mlocationManager = null; // < -- 4 -- >
                Log.d("ALARM", getCurrentDateTime() +  ", timeout");
            }
        }.start();
        mlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDTS,
                MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDTS,
                locationListener
        );
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ALARM", getCurrentDateTime() + ", exc: " + e.getMessage()); < -- 5 -- >
    }
}

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    /// other required methods overridden here ...

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        cdTimer.cancel();
        cdTimer = null;
        mlocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); // < -- 6 -- >
        mlocationManager = null;
        String latLng = " {" + location.getLatitude() + ":" + location.getLongitude() + "}";
        Log.d("ALARM",  getCurrentDateTime() + latLng);
    }
}
```

}

So, *context* (mark "< -- 1 -- >"), coming to `onReceive` is not null.
In note "< -- 2 -- >" I instantiate `CountDownTimer` with *constant* `RConstants.locUpdateTimeoutUsed`. The problem is, it defined and assigned outside of `AlarmReceiver`, so, when my `Activity` is killed, `RConstants.locUpdateTimeoutUsed` comes declared, but not defined. So, `CountDownTimer` constructs with (0, 0) values. That's why it's instance - `cdTimer`, fires `onFinish()` hardly being *started*. Here it *cancels* update for `mLocationManager` and sets it to NULL. But before `mLocationManager` completely stopped, method `onLocationChanged` manages to work, so, in line *< -- 6 -- >* caughts *exception*.